# Calling overloading main method

Tags: java

Assume that we have a class with two overloaded main methods.

```
    public class MyClass {
  public static void main(int x){
   System.out.println("(int x )version");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("(String[] args)");
  }
}
```

So, how do we call the (int x) version while running the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can overload main

No, you cannot start you program calling an overload,
JVM will ever call the main signature main(String[] args) overload.

```
//JVM will call this method manually if you want
public static void main(String[] args,int a){
// some code
}

//JVM will call this method to start your program
public static void main(String[] args){ 
// some code 
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this special method has special overloading semantics.It can be overloaded but cannot be called using java <some int>. Thanks Danito for understanding my question.

Answer (score 3):

`MyClass.main(5)`

is an example of how to call it.

---

If you automatically want the `main(int)` method to be called, just call it from the `main(String[])`. I assume you want java to treat the inputs like ints. Here is a way to do it

```
public static void main(int ... ints) {
    // Process
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    main(Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray());
}
```

Comment: I know how to call the method, My doubt was, is it possible to call overloading main method  using java command. I know I was not precise. :-)

Comment: @Nealesh Sorry I did understand that but did not answer. No it is not possible, JVM will search for `public static void main(String[])` and throw an error if it is not found.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to call it is as you'd call any other static method, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // call other "main"
   main(5);
}
```

The issue is that the true main method's method signature must match precisely what the JVM is expecting for it to be. All other "main" method overloads are just simply like any other method to the JVM and will not be a location of automatic program startup.